# /node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js Module not found: Can't resolve 'async_hooks'

Tags: next.js, prisma

Bug description
Hello, I am new to Prisma. I have been trying to access Prisma database with nextjs. And every time I try to use PrismaClient from @prisma/client in a nextjs page, I have been seeing this error.

./node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:26236:39
Module not found: Can't resolve 'async_hooks'
null

How to reproduce
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

My Schema file

```
datasource db {
provider = "mysql"
url = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator client {
provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

model User {
id Int @default(autoincrement()) @id
email String @unique
name String
password String
createdAt DateTime @default(now())
updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}
```

I created a migration and ran with the following commands

npx prisma migrate save --experimental
npx prisma migrate up --experimental

Then I also run npx prisma generate

This is my register.tsx file where I am accessing the prisma client

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

interface RegisterProps {}

const Register: React.FC = ({}) => {
const router = useRouter();
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
const [name, setName] = useState("");

const submitHandler = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
try {
const user = await prisma.user.create({
data: {
email,
password,
name,
},
});
console.log(user);
router.push("/");
} catch (e) {
console.log(e);
}
};

return (
// my template goes here
);
};
```

export default Register;

After running this, I am getting this following error

/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'async_hooks'
null

Expected behavior
I expect this code to build my page first. But it fails to do so and shows me the error in the title.

Prisma information
All of these information was included in the steps to reproduce part

Environment & setup
OS: Ubuntu
Database: MySQL
Node.js version: 14.05
Prisma version: 2.11.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to use `PrismaClient` directly on the frontend. You can only call it in the server-side methods that NextJS supports like [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering).

Comment: So how do I create data in the database with prisma? Because I need the state values to login and register without using the api

Comment: I don't think it's possible without the API.

Comment: This is for sure? we cant use prisma client on FE this tutorial shows like it can be
https://daily.dev/blog/nextjs-with-prisma

Comment: @MarkoBlazekovic Next.js is server-rendered, so Prisma can be used only parts that are run on the server, i.e. `getServerSideProps` or `getStaticProps`.